# Unable to access Apache2 HTTPD server on browser from remote machine

Tags: apache2, apache

I have a website deployed on Apache2. The Apache2 server is setup on a VM.
When I try to access the site using a browser from a remote machine (my laptop), I get a connection timed out error.
When I try to access something deployed on Tomcat on the same VM it works fine. But Apache gives a problem.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) check that the httpd process is running

```
ps -ef | grep httpd |grep -v grep
```

2) make sure you are broadcasting on port 80

```
netstat -atn |grep :80
```

3) verify in your conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf) file that you are binding Apache to port 80

```
<virtualhost *:80>
```

or

```
<virtualhost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
```

Your Tomcat process may be bound to port 80 and the socket is not available.

Comment: 1) Ran the command. Did not get any output.
2) tcp  0  0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
3) There was no directory named /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
I checked the directory /etc/apache2/ports.conf
The contents are:

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
</IfModule>

I've tried shutting down the Tomcat server and accessing the site. But it doesn't work.

Comment: httpd is Redhat/Centos. Looks like You are running Debian/Ubuntu. Check that Apache is running. Try: `ps -ef | grep apache2 | grep -v grep`

Comment: Yes I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

The Output is
**bold**root 28595 1 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
**bold**www-data 28600 28595 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
**bold**www-data 28601 28595 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
**bold**www-data 28602 28595 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
**bold**www-data 28603 28595 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
**bold**www-data 28604 28595 0 18:33 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Comment: It maybe a firewall issue if you are unable to access a remote machine. on the server verify you can load the docroot via `wget http://localhost` Open the file to verify html markup and not a 50x or 404 error. If that is fine you have to check either local firewall on iptables or external firewall from your provider to see that port 80 is accessible from the outside.

Comment: When I wget I get 404 Not Found Error.
I have set DocumentRoot to /var/www where there is an index.html file.

Comment: In the error log I see the message "File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs"

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. Now wget works. But I'm still unable to access the page from a remote system on the browser.

Comment: If you are running on AWS check that your security group has port 80 open. If behind a physical firewall, a network administrator must open it up. Otherwise locally it may be IPTABLES.

Answer (score 2):

on centos run this commands:

1. iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
2. /etc/init.d/iptables save

Comment: in order to ensure that the problem is due to 'iptables' , u can firstly, stop iptables [service iptables stop] then if u have access, start iptables [service iptables start] and run the above commands.